# Struts 2 Jquery tab navigation

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

When navigating from one tab to another, i.e, on clicking the submit button in a tab1 (which is jsp) the tab2 has to get loaded. My code is below.

```
  <sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" onCompleteTopics="tabcomplete"
    onChangeTopics="tabchange">
    <sj:tab id="tab1" href="test1.jsp" label="Tab One" />
    <sj:tab id="tab2" href="test2.jsp" label="Tab Two" />           
   </sj:tabbedpanel><sj:submit></sj:submit>
```

---

The jsp I have used is

```
 <s:url var="remoteurl1" action="ajax1" />
 <s:url var="remoteurl2" action="ajax2" />
 <sj:tabbedpanel id="tabpanel">
<sj:tab id="tab1" href="Test1.jsp" label="Tab One" />
<sj:tab id="tab2" href="Test2.jsp" label="Tab Two" />
 </sj:tabbedpanel>
 <sj:a href="#" onClickTopics="movetonextdiv" button="true">Next</sj:a>
```

and my script is

```
  $.subscribe('movetonextdiv', function(event, data) {
                   var selected = $("#tabpanel").tabs('option', 'selected');
                   $("#tabpanel").tabs('option', 'selected', selected + 1);
            });
```

I still face an issue like in the developer tools I am getting the error as Object  doesn't support this property or method for the below line of code.

```
  var selected = $("#tabpanel").tabs("option", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
<sj:a href="#" onClickTopics="movetonextdiv" button="true">Next</sj:a>


<script>
    $.subscribe('movetonextdiv', function(event, data) {
                    var selected = $("#tabpanel").tabs("option", "selected");
                    $("#tabpanel").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
                });
</script>

<sj:tabbedpanel id="tabpanel" >...</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.I still face an issue like in the developer tools i am getting the error as  Object doesn't support this property or method for the below line of code.
  
   var selected = $("#tabpanel").tabs("option", "selected");

Comment: have you replaced `tabpanel` with `remotetabs` according to your code ?

Comment: Ya i did i have replaced as id="tabpanel" in my code.. still  it didnt work

Comment: post complete code & also the libraries/POM. Seems like a `sj plugin` version issue to me.

Comment: The jars were struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1.jar
struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar

Comment: I have used the code same as mentioned in Answer.I have also changed id="tabpanel"

Comment: some other javascript/jquery plugin might be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should upgrade plugin to at least v3.6.1. Put `$.subscribe` before the tag which sets topics to publish that you subscribed to. Make sure you have jQuery UI enabled.

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true" />
```

the script to sibscribe topics

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.subscribe('movetonextdiv', function(event, data) {
      var el = $("#localtabs");
      var size = el.find(">ul >li").size();
      var active = el.tabs('option', 'active');
      el.tabs('option', 'active', active + 1>=size?0:active + 1);
    });
  });
</script>
```

tabs with navigator button

```
<sj:a href="#" onClickTopics="movetonextdiv" button="true">Next</sj:a>
<br/>
<sj:tabbedpanel id="localtabs" cssClass="list">
  <sj:tab id="tab1" target="jsp" label="JSP Code"/>
  <sj:tab id="tab2" target="javascript" label="JavaScript"/>
  <sj:tab id="tab3" target="java" label="Java"/>
  <div id="jsp">
    JSP
  </div>
  <div id="javascript">
    JavaScript
  </div>
  <div id="java">
    Java
  </div>
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```