# How to do the Dynamic tab creation in web Application?

Tags: html, xml, jsp, jakarta-ee, user-interface

I have to show the Dynamic tab in one of the application ,
We have a design in such that we would provide config xml file(have tab details with html/jsp
) to the client and they can modify the xml as per the client need,So based on the provided input ,the webapplication should possess the ability to show those tabs in the web page.

I  have a  xml as like below

```
<DynamicTabs>
 <Tab value="1">
  <Name>Tab1</Name>
  <FileName>Tab1.html</FileName>
 </Tab>
 <Tab value="2"> 
  <Name>Tab2</Name>
  <FileName>Tab2.html</FileName>
 </Tab>
 <Tab value="3">
  <Name>Tab3</Name>
  <FileName>Tab3.html</FileName>
 </Tab>
</DynamicTabs>
```

output:

```
Tab1| Tab2 |Tab3
```

So by reading the xml file i have o show the tabs in web page.
I am new to web application world,
Can you please tell which framework(like spring/struts in j2ee world) having these kind of features and Please provide your suggestions to accomplish it.

Comment: Some clicks, some links + css + javascript. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21266903/573032

Comment: Is that possible in spring frame work??

Comment: yes, of course, but it might be difficult to implement it yourself.

Comment: You should be looking to adopt a UI framework like [tag:Primefaces] or [tag:richfaces]