# Detect change of value of struts2 autocompleter tag using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, struts2, dojo

I am working on Struts 2 application. In my application, I need to use Struts 2 `autocompleter` tag. For that I have used `struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.1.2.jar` jar file. I need to fetch the value from autocompleter once the value changes. I tried using `onchange` event but it was not working. Here is my code:

```jsp
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc() {
    var a = dojo.widget.byId("country");
    var value1 = a.getSelectedValue();
    document.getElementById("myText").value = value1;
}
</script>
<sx:head />
</head>
<body>
<sx:autocompleter name="country"
id="country" onchange="abc();" list="cricketNations" />
</body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve this. Help me solve this issue.

Comment: Why not did you use jquery code?

Comment: Jquery code for what?

Comment: jquery for code or jquery code for script.

Comment: @RoshanYengul, did you try my solution below?

Comment: @RomanC I tried with JQuery too. But that too did not work for me. here is my jquery code:
    `<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#country").change(function() {
   alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
 });
</script>`

Comment: @RoshanYengul The plugin is using jquery is called struts2-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `struts2-dojo-plugin` is deprecated. You need to use [`<sj:autocompleter>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag) from [struts2-jquery-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts2-jquery-plugin).

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="myText" class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>

   <sj:autocompleter name = "country"
                       id = "country" 
           onChangeTopics = "autocompleteChange" 
                     list = "%{cricketNations}" />
   <script>
     $.subscribe('autocompleteChange', function(event, data) {
       var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
       var message = ui.item.value;
       if (ui.item.key) {
         message = '( '+ ui.item.key +' ) '+message;
       }
       $('#myText').html('&lt;b&gt;'+message+'&lt;/b&gt;');
     });
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome solution. It is way better than Dojo autocompleter. Thank you very much @RomanC

Comment: one more question. What if I want to get the selected value on the click on button? How do I get that? Will `document.getElementById()` work for this?

Comment: There's `onClickTopics` attribute that you can use to subscribe on the click event. I've used it for [tab navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21266903/573032).

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to use HTML attributes with dojo widgets, you need to use [dojo topics](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/topic.html) to subscribe for an event:

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/countryName", function(value, key, text, widget){
        alert('inside onchange');

        document.getElementById("myText").value = value;

    });

</script>
<sx:head />
</head>
<body>
<sx:autocompleter name="country" valueNotifyTopics="/countryName"  list="cricketNations" />
</body>
</html>
```

When value is selected for `sx:autocompleter`, topics will be published. See  `autocompleter` doc [here](http://struts.apache.org/docs/autocompleter.html).

Comment: My bad, I used "/country" as notify string, which was causing the issue. Please try with the updated code.

Comment: It is still not working even after updating the code.