# Creating and submit Multitab form in jsp and struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am now modifying a website where i got a requirement.Earlier we were having a table with a set of records on a data say student and when we click "Edit Student" button,the student data appears on a screen ,We can edit it and submit it as form submit.And in java end it maps automatically with a Student.java pojo when comes to action class.The student.java pojo is like given below

### Student.java

```
Public class Student extends FormEntity{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //Other basic fields
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    //respective getters and setters
}
```

Now my requirement is that instead of one Student we should have the provision to edit two or more student forms(Based on the check box selected among list of students) in a single page and submit it one time.I have some doubts on how to acheive this efficiently.Like with respect to transactions and all.I cannot afford to load it as seperate forms and submit since i need to manage transactions in the application.If i submit as seprate forms , each submit will be considered as seperate transactions.I want everything as same transaction.And also how to load forms dynamically.I mean as far now the form is a jsp where i have handled some onload events based on the Ids,Now i dont know how to change it as i will have to give the ids dynamically now.Is there any possiblity in struts that i can use that would allow the form submitted to be taken as list of object(List) so that i can use it for my transaction management that i was discussing earlier.Can anyone suggest me on how can i develop this requirement.

Comment: Yes you can submit a list.

Comment: It's difficult to predict but you can use [multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21266903/573032).

Comment: @Aleksandr : ya.. I found that we can submit a list by having two or more form elements with same name. But in my case I want to get the entire form as list since I want to iterate the entire form for my processing

Comment: I think you can add/remove new rows by `javascript` in client side. Then when user submits, you will have all of them including new rows and deleted rows. Then write your code to process the list and create your transaction against db. I found a tutorial where you may get some ideas at http://javaonlineguide.net/2014/10/struts-2-adding-removing-dynamic-rows-and-getting-values-in-struts-2-action.html

Comment: @user2078883 You can have a `List<Student>` in the controller and post data from the single form.